# Is there a way to do this so I don't have 64 if statements?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, io

I was told to create a 2D array from a txt file that had the "carModel, carColor" followed by a new line. 
The 2D array is 8x8 and for each time a certain carmore and carcolor appear, their respective [x][y] coordinate that represents their count goes up by 1.

So far, I have read the file, created a 2D array from the file, and have created an output with the 2D array and every slot filled with zero, but the only way I can seem to figure out to update each model,color count is if I manually make 64 if-statements to check if they appear in the list n+ times. 
Surely there has to be another way?

For example, When my scanner reads through the list, I need it to check if the list repeats the carmodel,carcolor and if so, update the count of that carmake and color.

This is the code I have thus far:

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception
{
    String [][] cars = new String [8][8]; 
    ArrayList <String> colors = new ArrayList<>();
    colors.add("BLUE  ");
    colors.add("BLACK ");
    colors.add("BROWN ");
    colors.add("GREEN ");
    colors.add("RED   ");
    colors.add("SILVER");
    colors.add("WHITE ");
    Collections.sort(colors);
    ArrayList <String> models = new ArrayList<>();
    models.add("Escape  ");
    models.add("Explorer");
    models.add("F150    ");
    models.add("F250    ");
    models.add("Flex    ");
    models.add("Mustang ");
    models.add("Taurus  ");
    Collections.sort(models);
    cars [0][0] = "_____  ";
    for (int a = 1; a < cars.length; a++)
    {
        cars[0][a] = (models.get(a-1)) + " ";
    }
    for (int b = 1; b < cars.length; b++)
    {
        cars[b][0] = (colors.get(b-1)) + " ";
    }
    for (int fir = 1; fir < cars.length; fir++)
    {
        for (int sec = 1; sec < cars[1].length; sec++)
        {
            if (cars[fir][sec] == null)
            {
                cars[fir][sec] = "0        ";
            }
        }
    }       
    for (int first = 0; first < cars.length; first++)
    {
        for (int second = 0; second < cars[first].length; second++)
        {
            System.out.print(cars[first][second]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }        
    File file = new File ("C:\\Users\\delta\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\SchoolWork\\cars.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    String ab = sc.nextLine();
        while (ab != null)
        {
            String [] nums = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < nums.length;i++)
            {                  
               System.out.println(nums[i]);                    
            }               
        }        
}
```

the output is supposed to look something like this:
[image]

Comment: Ask this at [codereview.se]

Comment: Not sure if it makes sense to, but it may, cover your Model and Colour to enums and use their ordinal as the array index. No secondary looping, just scan, split, Model.valueOf, Colour.valueOf, increment martix[make.ordinal, Colour.ordinal]++. This assumes you can use int[] [] instead of string and that enums actually make sense with the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is use the `ArrayList.indexOf()` method.

1. Get the index for the color.
2. Get the index for the model.

And then use those to set or increment the entry in the 8x8 array. for each time you read in the color and model of the car.

```
    int[][] count = new int[][];

    while (reading in data) {
       get color
       get model
       int row = modelList.indexOf(model)
       int col = colorList.indexOf(color)
       count[row][col]++
    }
```

I also recommend you trim the white space surrounding both the color and the model.  It can make debugging difficult and you don't need it to format the output as long as you use `System.out.printf()`.

Comment: I am not exactly sure the logic or coding that goes behind what you are trying to say. I believe you mean I would do something like "for each string in String[] nums if each.equals(nums[i]) then cars [colors.indexOf(I)][models.indexOf[i] += 1" or something like that perhaps?